# TypeLoadException when creating a custom renderer

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, .net-assembly

I have an Android app created in Xamarin.Forms (4.7.0) and I want to implement ads from AdMob into it. For that i have to create a ViewRenderer wrapper around a View class that I made earlier. As soon as i add this line into the ViewRenderer

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AdBanner), typeof(AdBanner_Droid))]
```

then build and launch the app, I get this error :

```
System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type DDKTCKE.Controls.AdBanner, APP_NAME, Version=1.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null while decoding custom attribute: (null)'
```

I already tried :

1. Deleteing bin and obj folders
2. Wiping data from test device
3. Cleaning the solution

A also used the exact same code in a new blank project and it worked as it should. What could be causing problems in my main project ? What should I look into ?

Answer (score 1):

To implement the Android renderer, two classes are needed; an `AdBanner` class in the Forms project (or an Netstandard project as a project reference to the Forms project) and an `AdBannerRenderer` in an Android project:

`AdBanner:`

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class AdBanner: View
    ...
```

`AdBannerRenderer:`

```
using Android.Gms.Ads; 
using Xamarin.Forms; 
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using AdBanner = MyProject.AdBanner; 

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AdBanner), typeof(Droid.Renderers.AdBannerRenderer))] 
namespace Droid.Renderers 
{ 
    public class AdBannerRenderer : ViewRenderer<AdBanner, AdView> 
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! But I do have both of these classes.

Comment: Are the classes in namespaces and in assemblies that actually are project references, and are the namespaces of the classes the expected namespaces?

Answer (score 0):

I created a new project and copied all my code from my old solution into it. Now everything works flawlessly.

So once again this was a problem with VS that just popped up for no good reason and took me a week to find a f̶i̶x̶  workaround. And people wonder how anyone could hate Visual Studio.